# Can SharpPcap find Ethernet itself?

Tags: c#, packet-capture, sharppcap, packetdotnet

Can SharpPcap auto choose Ethernet for capturing packets?

```cs
var device = CaptureDeviceList.Instance[3];//I don't want to hard-code it.
```

Should I use "if, else" or "for-loop" to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Foreach-loop:

```cs
var devices = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;
foreach (var i in devices)
    {
        string Local_eth = "Ethernet";
        if (i.Description.Contains(Local_eth))
        {
            codes;
        }
```

Comment: Or, better, use LINQ: `var device = CaptureDeviceList.Instance.FirstOrDefault(dev => dev.Description.Contains("Ethernet"));` (You should check whether `dev` is null or not before using it though.)

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly, thanks so much. I'm new at C#(I'm better at python). This is my first project with C#(Create Windows Service).